# Pasar HTML a imagen

Tags: javascript, php, html

Mi problema es el siguiente, necesito una libreria js o PHP para poder pasar código HTML a una imagen y esta se descargue automaticamente.

```
$html = "<div><p>Soy un código HTML</p></div>"

htmltoPNG(<?php echo $html ?>);
<script>
        function htmltoPNG(html) {
          //Codigo que convierta el html a una imagen png
          descarga(imagen);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Pasar código html a una imagen, para que necesitas código html en la imagen?

Comment: vote para cerrarla como no relacionado, pero aquí tienes un [ink](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/):

Comment: Lo más genérico es usar PhantomJS porque se puede crear una imagen de cualquier momento del HTML (incluso después de haber terminado de cargar y correr los JS que lo completen).

Comment: Entiendo que quieres realizar un screenshoot, Mírate https://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png/blob/master/webkit2png

Comment: @Elenasys lo necesitaba para una cosa de mi trabajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/es/example) puedes convertir `html` a `jpg` :

```
<?php
 require_once('html2_pdf_lib/html2pdf.class.php');

if(isset($_POST['snapshot'])){
   $html = stripslashes($_POST['url']); 
   ob_start(); 

?>

<page style="font-size: 14px">
<?php
   echo $html;
?>
</page>
<?php 
   $content = ob_get_clean();
   ob_clean ();


  try
  {
      $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');

      $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('courier');
      $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
      $file = $html2pdf->Output('temp.pdf','F');
      //pdf creation

      $im = new imagick('temp.pdf');
      $im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
      $img_name = time().'.jpg';
      $im->setSize(300,200);
      $im->writeImage($img_name);
      $im->clear();
      $im->destroy(); 
      //remove temp pdf
      unlink('temp.pdf');
 }
 catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
 }
}
```