# Error Plugin CakePdf

Tags: php, cakephp

Estoy usando el *plugin* **CakePdf** (Para generar PDF) dentro de un servidor **CentOS 7** y para ello e instalado el programa ***Wkhtmltopdf***, pero cuando trato de descargar algún  **PDF** desde la aplicación me sale este error:

> WKHTMLTOPDF didn't return any data

he realizado la configuración según indica la 
[Documentación](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf)

La versión de ***Cakephp*** que uso es 3.3

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo de como estas utilizando?

Comment: Este post podria [ayudarte](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8689/pasar-html-a-imagen/8690#8690).

Comment: mi codigo esta asi

Comment: `Plugin::load('CakePdf',['bootstrap'=> true,'routes'=>true]);
Configure::write('CakePdf',[
    'engine' => [
        'className' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
        'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
        'options' => [
            'print-media-type' => false,
            'outline' => true,
            'dpi' => 96
        ],
    ],
    'download' => true
]);` esa es la configuracion